# My alloy plausibility

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science

My armour is able to take temperatures upto 500°c and tensile strength of 17 MPa . It is made with some knowledge of physics and material science. My suit is made of mono-crystalline iron and coated with tetrafluoroethylene plastic. Can it be made using this materials ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post so that you describe what you mean by withstand so much force and heat. Without knowing that we can't meaningfully remark on whether teflon coated mono-crystalline iron will do the job.

Comment: It will need to heat resistant and durable material that's it what I described it

Comment: Pyrex, a common form of glass used in kitchen appliances is heat resistant and durable compared to other glasses. I don't think it would meet your criteria for armor. If you don't [edit] your post to explicitly describe your standard for durability and heat resistance, your question will likely be closed for lack of detail and clarity.

Comment: [Tetrafluoroethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrafluoroethylene) has a boiling point at -86C and its gaseous at normal temperatures. Did you mean [polytetrafluoroethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene#Properties) aka Teflon? That one melts at 327C.

Comment: Welcome Bala (if no-one had already said it). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when, enjoy the site.

Comment: Yes it teflon like

Comment: @BalaMurugan, just to check; you need it to have a tensile strength of 17 megapascals (Mpa), not  17 millipascals (mpa), as there is a significant difference.

Comment: Seriously, Bala, just forget the PTFE. Anything that resists 2 minutes of exposure _on the same spot_ to a focused 40W infrared laser has my respects, and it looks like a [3-5mm thick of cake of starch, baking soda and PVA glue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_6fONbnIUI) **is** that thing

Answer (score 4):

From [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-69387-z), the tensile strength of iron crystals is over $100Mpa$, and its melting point is [over $1000°C$](https://www.onlinemetals.com/en/melting-points), so that part works.

But you will encounter problems with  the polytetrafluoroethylene plastic, as it [melts at 370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene#Properties).

So the outer coating would melt off if the amour was exposed to $500°C$ for extended periods (more then a few seconds). If the heat is only present for a short time then it might work as only a small amount of the coating would melt, and would then conduct the heat to the rest of the amount cooling/solidifying the molten portion.

hopefully this helps

Comment: Well, yeah, the armor will withstand 500C, no problem. However, the thing that the armor is meant to protects? That one is properly toasted inside the [black red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_heat) armor. I personally would prefer to wear an armor of toasted bread - at least, when carbonized, it's a [good thermal insulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqR4_UoBIzY)

Comment: PFTE subjected to lots of heat will decompose into some really thoroughly unpleasant fluorine compounds which are toxic and corrosive. Probably not a great material to use in this context.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Agreed the armor isn't great for long term heating, especially as the armor (the steel and the plastic) won't withstand constant 500C, as the plastic would melt, (or as StarfishPrime points out, it would decompose into toxic products), the only way it wouldn't be a problem is it the heat provided by temperature source is less than the heat required to cause the PFTE warm to a temperature where decomposition/melting occurs.